# JSONP with Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsonp, laravel

Browser sends JSONP requets to Laravel, Laravel returns the results to browser. In the brower console, I get the warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

I believe this is due to improper headers in the JSONP response? How should this warning be fixed?

**PHP**

```
$callback = Input::get('callback');
$result = DB::table('users')->find(123);

return $callback . '(' . json_encode($result) . ')';
```

`Response::JSON($result)` will return the usual JSON response I believe, not the JSONP variant with the callback function name wrapping around the payload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the headers in the Response::json() call.

```
Response::json($result, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/javascript'));
```

The correct MIME type for JSONP is application/javascript.

Answer (score 25):

You can do this in Lavavel 4: (Original: Tu puedes hacer esto en Laravel 4)

```
Response::json($result)->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Response::json($result)->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
```

is better as suggested by [Raul Duran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17429575/1718312) as you don't have to manipulate the $result.

The other option is echo instead of using the Response.

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel(5.1 and above) or Lumen(5.1 and above):

if you would like to create a JSONP response, you may use the JSON method in addition to  setCallback:

```
return response()
    ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
    ->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel>8, to create a JSONP response:

```
return response()
        ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
        ->withCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

we should use **withCallback()** instead of **setCallback()**

according to Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses)